# Nuget package restore is not working on TFS build server

Tags: nuget, tfsbuild

I followed [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2012/05/10/using-nuget-with-tfs-build-automation.aspx) blog post and I expected Nuget to just work. It obviously has not. I get errors on all of my third party dll's that I expect NuGet to update automatically:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\
Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "bin\AutoMapper.dll"
 because it was not found.
```

I have set everything up correctly and I have ensured that the solution has Package restore enabled. If I delete a package locally and build, NuGet restores that package for me.

I am not sure why it is not fuctioning on the build server though.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add NugetRestore Activity to the TFS workfolw

[image]

Note:

For Team Foundation Build 2013 on-premises and Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Team Foundation Service), the default Build Process Templates already implement the NuGet Package Restore workflow without any special configuration.

Comment: Do you have a link for adding this?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bb358183-5552-4ee9-a6ef-528db24e65d0/how-to-use-the-nugetrestore-activity?forum=tfsbuild




http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore-with-team-build

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar error for log4net nuget package and I solved it in a different way. May be this will be useful to someone some day.

**The error from TFS Team Build 2015**

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\
Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "bin\Log4net.dll"
 because it was not found.`

**Cause**

The path to the nuget package in the .csproj file for referencing the package in the project cannot be found

**Resolution**

Edit the .csproj file of the project that has the error.
Look for the node `ItemGroup`in the .csproj file
You will see the `HintPath` pointing to a folder, most like the folder contain the name of solution as where it will file the DLL.
Replace the `HintPath` with     `<HintPath>..\..\Assemblies\3rd party\log4net\1.2.10.0\2.0\log4net.dll</HintPath>`

You nuget package library may not be log4net but a different library. A very easy way would be to be edit the .csproj file of a project in the solution that contains the same nuget package library, copy the reference of the nuget in the `ItemGroup` and replace in the project that has the error. The reference should start contain `...\Assemblies\3rd party\ ...` instead of a physical file location on your machine